# SourceHandler Writer null when calling informWriterError, fail to work

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ei, wso2-esb

I deployed an API in EI. The API's main logic transformed a rest request to soap request and the calling a soap-based endpoint. Later I use a data mapper converting the response message to the format which I need.
But sometimes the endpoint went wrong and respond an error message, which made the data mapper parsed mistakenly and the main process went to the default fault sequence(I put a response mediator to the fault sequence), then I got an error log "SourceHandler Writer null when calling informWriterError".
After the scenario occurs again and again(about 200times in 5 minutes), the EI couldn't deal request any longer.

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

I used the version 6.1.1 before, there is a bug https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/650.

After upgraded to the version 6.4.0 release, everything is ok now.